# How to prevent editing of text in a UITextField without disabling other events using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I'm trying to modify the text rendered in the `UITextField` based on certain events such as `Touch Down` or `Touch Down Repeat`. I want the `UITextField` to be responsive only to events but prevent users from modifying the actual value in the `UITextField`.

I have tried unchecking the `Enabled` state of the `UITextField` but that causes it to not respond to touch events either.

How do I prevent users from changing the contents of the `UITextField` without affecting the response to touch events, specifically using Swift 3?

Comment: Try override `shouldBeginEditting` and return false

Comment: Implement the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method and return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was finally able to get this working in the expected manner. What I did was -

1 - Extend the UITextFieldDelegate in the `ViewController` class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

2 - Inside the function `viewDidLoad()`, assign the textfield delegate to the controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textfield.delegate = self
}
```

(you will have assign each UITextField's delegate that you want to be prevented from editing)

3 - Lastly, implement your custom behavior in the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` function

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

For reference, check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) API Reference on Apple Developer

Answer (score 0):

Override textFieldShouldBeginEditing , and return false.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(state: UITextField) -> Bool {
 return false
}
```

you can also disable for specific text field.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
 if(textField == self.myTextField){
   return false
   }
 return true;
}
```